# Hostile takeovers: Does your civilization receive the benefits of wonders?

Tags: civilization-5

When taking over another civilization's city, for instance, a city that has [the oracle](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Oracle_%28Civ5%29), does it contribute +1 to your civilization's culture as a puppet?  When annexed, will the wonder remain in the city and contribute the +1 culture as well?

Does this apply for all wonders, or just a subset?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

All buildings in puppeted cities contribute towards your civilization. So money-making buildings, for example, add money to your civilizations. Wonders share this behavior, and you'll get that +1 culture from The Oracle.

Notice that when a city is conquered, each building has a chance of being destroyed; in particular, all defensive buildings (such as walls) and all culture buildings (such as monuments) are destroyed. Wonders, however, do not get destroyed and remain in that city (with the exception of national wonders).